# lightdm and xfce - password prompt invisible after locking

Tags: xfce, suspend, screen-lock, lightdm

just updated from LinuxMint 18.3 to 19.0, found a weird problem in locking and unlocking screen.

Closing the laptop lid puts the computer to suspend, but when opening it, the password prompt for unlocking is not there, instead just the screen before I close the lid. I thought it was freezing, but actually not! When I just type my password as usual, it will unlock and everything is fine! So it's just the password prompt somehow becomes invisible, although it's actually there.

A few more observations:

- if i click in the area where there should be the 'switch the user' button, it will take me to the login window
- if i use xflock4 in cmd line, everything would be as expected and the password prompt is there

Anyone experience something similar?

> Xfce Power Manager 1.6.1
>
> light-locker 1.8.0
>
> lightdm 1.26.0

Comment: So you’re saying it *looks like* the screen before you close the lid, but you don’t really have access to any of your windows? And, if you type characters, nothing appears to happen, but if you type your password and Enter, everything goes back to normal? What happens if you type something other than your password? How about Esc or Tab? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: after removing gnome-screensaver, the issue was gone